# Create Data Studio assets by API call

Tags: looker-studio

Is there a way to create Data Studio assets (data sources, reports) by some api call. There is no appropriate endpoint in official api, but maybe there is some workaround, for example using google drive api or something.

Have anyone tried to solve this kind of issue? Will appreciate any advice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently (Aug 2020) not supported.